# android MediaPlayer - illegalstateException on MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have the following piece of code.
ex:

```
 if(player1 != null){
    if(player1.isPlaying()){ //check if it playing
        //other code

    }
    }
```

**QUESTION 1:**
The condition check for null always passes even though the media player as finished playing and i release the player on oncompletion.
//release on completion of the player

```
player1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Media player has completed playing");

                }
            });
```

**QUESTION 2:** 
IF the player HAS finished playing, a check for `null` still returns false and it fails as `isPlaying` giving an `illegalstateexception`.

Comment: Are you under the impression that calling 'release' on your media player will cause all references to become `null`? Any reference you hold to a media player will continue to be non-null even after you call release. It only becomes null when you explicitly set it to null.

Comment: Tim: thanks for the quick response. then how do i check if the player has finished playing. calling player1.isPlaying without the null check condition also gives an illegalstateexception

Comment: I don't see a good way to do this from the MediaPlayer class itself. You can't call isPlaying on a released mediaPlayer, and you can't test if a MediaPlayer instance has been released. All I can suggest is to rework your program such that you can null `player1` immediately after you release it.

Comment: Yes. thats a good point and exactly what i was thinking of doing. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Releasing the player doesnt nullify the instance. Add null after release if thats what you want.

```
player1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                    mp = null;
                    Log.d(TAG, "Media player has completed playing");

                }
            });
```